# remove file from file system if file is 30 days and older?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to delete files that are older than  30 days , so everytime `readDirectory` is called i want to check and remove the file older than 30 days.

so below code is not removing the file, any idea what is implemented wrong or better thoughts on this ?

service.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var currentDate = new Date();

function readDirectory(callback) {
    var dirPath = './logs/dit';
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    var objToReturn = [];


    //this will get you list of all files. in directory
    async.eachSeries(files, function(file, callback) {
        var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
        var fileInfo = {};
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
            fileInfo.fileDate = stats.birthtime;
            //write stats data into objToReturn
            /*fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, items) {*/
            fileInfo.filename = file;
            compareDates(fileInfo);
            /* });*/
            objToReturn.push(fileInfo);
            callback();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        //final callback when all files completed here send objToReturn to client
        callback(objToReturn);
    });
}


function compareDates(file) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - file.fileDate.getTime());
    var dayDifference = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    console.log('Days difference in Dates', dayDifference);
    //                        return dayDifference;
    if (dayDifference == 1) {
        fs.unlink('.logs/dit' + file.filename, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // file doens't exist
                console.info("File doesn't exist, won't remove it.");
            } else {
                console.log('removed file', file);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You're missing a `/` here `fs.unlink('.logs/dit...`

Comment: ok is it the best approach to achieve this task ?